# LPTSTR contains only one letter

Tags: c++, dll, unicode, lptstr, lpwstr

I'm creating a DLL for a application. The application calls the DLL and receives a string from 8 to 50 in length.

The problem I'm having is that **only the first letter** of any message the application receives is shown.

Below is the GetMethodVersion function.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
STDAPI_(void) GetMethodVersion(LPTSTR out_strMethodVersion, int in_intSize)
{
   if ((int)staticMethodVersion.length() > in_intSize)
       return;
   _tcscpy_s(out_strMethodVersion, 12, _T("Test")); 
   //staticMethodVersion should be insted of _T("Test")
}
```

The project settings are set to Unicode.
I belive after some research that there is a problem with Unicode format and how it functions. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Why are there three strings in the code, `out_strMethodVersion`, `staticMethodVersion`, `out_String`?

Comment: Sorry, removed a bunch on unnecessary code, and must have missed a renaming

Comment: Where do you see a single letter, in one of Visual Studio's Debug windows, or in console or your app's GUI? Maybe the string is Unicode, but Visual Studio thinks that it is not? Look at the string directly in memory, and see if there are other letters separated with 00 bytes.

Comment: Problem is we have to guess a lot here, because the provided example is incomplete. Give us an example that we can paste and compile and observe the problem (first compile the example yourself like we would do, and confirm that the problem is still there in example as it is in your original code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote in your question that the project settings are Unicode: is this true for *both* the DLL and the calling EXE? Make sure that they both match.

In Unicode builds, the ugly TCHAR macros become:

```
LPTSTR      --> wchar_t*
_tcscpy_s   --> wcscpy_s
_T("Test")  --> L"Test"
```

So you have:

```
STDAPI_(void) GetMethodVersion(wchar_t* out_strMethodVersion, 
                               int in_intSize)
{
    ...
    wcscpy_s(out_strMethodVersion, 12, L"Test");
}
```

Are you sure the *"magic number"* 12 is correct? Is the destination string buffer pointed to by `out_strMethodVersion` of size at least 12 `wchar_t`s (including the terminating NUL)?

Then, have a look at the **call site** (which you haven't showed).

How do you print the returned string? Maybe you are using an **ANSI char function**, so the returned string is *misinterpreted* as a `char*` ANSI string, and so the first `0x00` byte of the Unicode UTF-16 string is misinterpreted as a NUL-terminator at the call site, and the string gets truncated at the first character when printed?

```
 Text:             T       e       s       t      NUL
 UTF-16 bytes:   54 00   65 00   73 00   74 00   00 00
     (hex)          **<--+
                         |
                 First 00 byte misinterpreted as 
               NUL terminator in char* ANSI string,
         so only 'T' (the first character) gets printed.
```

---

**EDIT**

The fact that you clarified in the comments that:

> I switched the DLL to ANSI, the EXE apparently was that as well, though the exe was documented as Unicode.

makes me think that the EXE assumes the **UTF-8** Unicode encoding.

Just as in ANSI strings, a `0x00` byte in UTF-8 is a string NUL terminator, so the previous analysis of UTF-16 `0x00` byte (in a `wchar_t`) *misinterpreted* as string NUL terminator applies.

Note that pure ASCII is a proper subset of UTF-8: so your code may work if you just use pure ASCII characters (like in `"Test"`) and pass them to the EXE.

However, if the EXE is documented to be using Unicode UTF-8, you may want to Do The Right Thing and return a UTF-8 string from the DLL.

The string is returned via `char*` (as for ANSI strings), but it's important that you make sure that **UTF-8** is the encoding used by the DLL to return that string, to avoid subtle bugs in the future.

While the general terminology used in Windows APIs and Visual Studio is *"Unicode"*, it actually means the *UTF-16* Unicode encoding in those contexts.

However, UTF-16 is not the only Unicode encoding available. For example, to exchange text on the Internet, the **UTF-8** encoding is widely used. In your case, it sounds like your EXE is expecting a Unicode UTF-8 string.

Comment: You post made me think. 
Until now I was assuming that the calling exe was unicoded since it was documented as such.
However switching to ANSI fixed it!

Comment: @PonWer Maybe the caller is using UTF-8 instead of UTF-16? The fact that switching to ANSI fixes the problem means that the caller is definitely not using UTF-16.

Comment: @PonWer: What exactly did you switch to ANSI? Both the DLL and the calling EXE? Or do you have a Unicode (UTF-16) DLL and an EXE built with ANSI/MBCS? Please clarify. Make sure that both the DLL and the calling EXE communicate using the _same_ text format, or provide proper conversion at the boundaries. As you can read in @RaymondChen's comment, there are different Unicode encodings, e.g. UTF-8 and UTF-16. I assumed _"Unicode == UTF-16"_ in my answer (which is the general assumption in Visual Studio, `_UNICODE/UNICODE` preprocessor macros, etc.).

Comment: I switched the dll to ANSI, the exe apparently was that as well, though the exe was documented as unicode.

Answer (score 0):

It is to late to `#define UNICODE` after `#include "stdafx.h"`. It should be defined before the first `#include` in `stdafx.h` itself. But the proper way is to set it in project properties (menu Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Character Set > "Use Unicode Character Set").

Comment: Alright thanks, I changed it in project settings, however the problem remains